# page load causes crash on the server

Tags: asp.net, iis, xslt, umbraco

I use umbraco with my website, when I try to load a specific page with a master that includes xslt templates, the site crashes. I get invalid request page. In the event viewer I can see the following details:

> Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 6.0.3790.3959, stamp 45d6968e, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.4480, stamp 49c51f0a, debug? 0, fault address 0x0000bef7.

The only information I can get about the crash is the url of the page(I use IISDebug tool). 
I want to make it clear that it occurs only for a specific page. It means that when I load the same master page with another similar pages, everything is OK.
It's very hard to figure out the problem like this, when the only information I have is the url.
Can you suggest me some debug tools or ways to debug?
(The site is on my client's server- windows server 2003 web edition -no VS on the server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a faulty macro or XSLT on that page - maybe something that is using Response.Write to alter the response after it's being sent?
My suggestion would be to set up the [Remote Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) on the server and use Visual Studio's "Attach to Process" to then remotely attach to the process as it faults - Visual Studio should then catch the exception, which should help you to isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm going to try the Remote Debugger. I'll let you know if I will catch something..